# New input placeholder behavior in Safari 10 - no longer hides on change via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, safari, macos-sierra

Safari 10.0 in macOS Sierra seems to have changed the way the placeholder in an input behaves when the input value is changed via JavaScript. It now also differs from what Chrome (53.0.2785.116) is doing.

**Until now,** when setting an input value via JavaScript the placeholder would disappear. After setting the value back to empty via JavaScript, the placeholder would reappear.

**Now,** setting the input value via JavaScript does not hide the placeholder, until the input gains focus afterwards (e.g. by being clicked on).

Check this JS Bin for a demo: https://jsbin.com/rogoludahu/edit?html,js,output

Is this the intended behavior? If so, is there a clever workaround for hiding/unhiding the placeholder after a change via JavaScript?

Edit: This has now been filed at rdar://28412751 for Safari 10 and the Safari Technology Preview.

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour! To me, this seems to be a bug

Comment: Most likely a bug. Rather hacky way to fix is to set the value twice as a temporary solution https://jsbin.com/qiloyuxura/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: try this maybe: document.getElementById("myInput").setAttribute('value', "New Value");

Comment: @DalinHuang: Nice idea, but no change for me - feel free to try in the JS Bin.

Comment: The placeholder seems to be working correctly in Safari 10.1 on OSX 10.12.4.  Still appears broken (seeing the overlapping placeholder) in iOS Safari on iOS 10.3.1.

Comment: @Paul: I can't seem to confirm your experience in macOS 10.12.4 with Safari 10.1 (Build 12603.1.30.0.34). My JS Bin above still shows the incorrect behavior, same with the current Safari Technology Preview. Would you mind checking again with the JS Bin?

Comment: Where is rdar://28412751?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved in Safari Technology Preview Release 37 (Safari 11.1, WebKit 12605.1.2) as well as in regular Safari Version 11.0.3 (WebKit 13604.5.6).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem earlier today. As far as I've seen, there is no good solution. My hacky workaround was to call `.focus()` and then `.blur()` on the element as soon as the value was given to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Apple thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7732774?start=0&tstart=0) (and confirmed by one of my coworkers), this is only an issue if you've opened the Javascript console. So, you probably don't need to worry about a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the bug returned or was never fixed properly (Safari 11.0.3). Can be reproducible with the jsbin from Joshua. The solution for us was to redraw the field on change. We are using ExtJS so this is a snipped for the field override, but should be able to apply it in any other framework or vanila.

```
if(Ext.isSafari && !Ext.isEmpty(me.emptyText)) {
    me.on('change', function() {
        var me = this;

        if(me.rendered && me.el && Ext.isFunction(me.el.redraw)) {
            me.el.redraw()
        }
    })  
}
```